# How to cd into a folder by clicking a path in the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a “todo” script in my Terminal where I add paths to folders that I am working on. For example:

```
badoop project X: /path/to/project/folder
```

Then the next day I run `badoop` and I get the list that I have added. I would love to be able to click on the path and the terminal to `cd` into it!

At the moment if I <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> it opens the folder in the Finder. But is there a way to get the Terminal to point to that path?

Comment: `cd ` then drag the folder to Terminal & hit Enter... or are you looking for a fully automated version?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes that's what I've ended up doing. Though if for example that was an `http` link, I would be able to `cmd` and click. I thought there'd be something like that for these baths